# outlook redemption as windows service

Tags: service, window, outlook-redemption

We have created a window service using outlook redemption (to read mail and save to DB) but it is giving following error, as per our log file, though at development studio environment when we debug it all works well.

```
Source: Error Message:
Description: Error in IMsgServiceAdmin::ConfigureMsgService: MAPI_E_DISK_ERROR
ulVersion: 0
Error: The file D:\Manoj Data\Mails\Manoj.pst cannot be opened.
Component: Personal Folders
ulLowLevelError: 0
ulContext: 268828930
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Does PST file actually exist?
Is Outlook running (and accessing that PST file) at the time your service is running?

Comment: Yes outlook is running and accessing the same file.

Comment: That's the problem: the security contexts are different, and the PST provider might not be able to share the file between different processes.

Comment: So what's the solution? as I want that the user keep using ms outlook and my redemption service keep doing its work (on same pst). Is it possible?

Comment: Are you running either Outlook or your service under elevated privileges? What version of Outlook are you using? What is the OS version?

Comment: Outlook and our service both are under same user account having privileges as admin. OS: windows 7, MS Outlook: 2007